# Check if UICollectionViewCell already created to avoid reuse

Tags: ios, initialization, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, reusability

I'll make it short.

**Situation**

Let say i have 5 cells, im doing some kind of "method" on UIView who's placed inside the cell(as a subview).
I need this "method" to occur only once(when the cell initialize),and avoid this "method" from happening again over the `cellForItemAtIndexPath`.

**What i have tried**

- In the `UICollectionViewCell` subclass, declare bool value `var alreadyCreated = false` and check inside the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` if the propery is `False` - meaning it havent created yet. and than run the "method" and change the propert to `True`. **Problem -** beacuse of the reuse even for cells that havent created yet, it set the property `alreadyCreated` to true.

**Any suggestions how to determine if the cell is already been created even when reusing cells?**

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I finally understood what the question is!

This is actually really easy, because the list that keeps track of this already exists. It's the data model.

So, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you are looking into the data model for this section/row and using that info to populate the cell.

Well, in that data model, you also need to have a Bool value that starts out `false`, and (in `cellForRow`) if it's `false` you switch it to `true` and do your one-time configuration. In that way, you end up doing this task exactly once for each apparent row of the table.

Really this is exactly the same as when I populate cells with images that need to be downloaded from the Internet. How do I know whether I've downloaded the image for this row? Because the image is right there in the model! If it's *not* there, I know I need to start downloading it. If it *is* there, I've done this work already and I just supply the image. Thus the image for every row is downloaded a maximum of once.

Comment: Matt, you are such an awesome guys for trying help me, is there any chance i can ope chat room with you? im not sure how to do that lol

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best approach, but you can store cell's indexes, where method is already finished. And when `cellForItemAtIndexPath` you can check if current indexPath is contained in array. If you have only one section you can store just `Int`'s.

Comment: This is my last resort, i thought about it as well , im trying to avoid it. I'm sure there is an better option than this, i mean its pretty basic thing dosent it?